# WSO2 EI Docker container 6.4.0 - Facing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded in ETL process

Tags: java, wso2, jvm, heap-memory, wso2-enterprise-integrator

There is ETL process running in WSO2 EI 6.4.0.

Flow: `Task Scheduler --> Proxy Service --> Sequence`

- Task scheduler will trigger proxy service based on cron expression(eg. `0 45 0/2 ? * * *` )
- Proxy service will fetch Data from source by using bigquery connector runQuery Operation and invoke sequence
- Inside Sequence, Iterate mediator placed to iterate each record and framing payload to invoke DSS which will push data to target system.

Below is the sample sequence code for reference:

```
<iterate expression="$body//rows" id="BigQID" sequential="true">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                    <property expression="//f[1]/v/text()" name="name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property expression="//f[2]/v/text()" name="email" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property expression="//f[3]/v/text()" name="phone" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    
                    <!--  Frame payload for DSS Call -->
                    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:wso2_dss_insert_op"/>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                                <Body>
                                    <wso2_dss_insert_op xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                        <name>$1</name>
                                        <email>$2</email>
                                        <phone>$3</phone>
                                    </wso2_dss_insert_op>
                                </Body>
                            </Envelope>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('name')"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('email')"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('phone')"/>
                            
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <!--  calling DSS to push data to eMite CDW DB -->
                    <call>
                        <endpoint>
                            <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/test-etl/services/WSO2_TEST_DSS/wso2_dss_insert_op">
                                <timeout>
                                    <duration>60000</duration>
                                </timeout>
                                <suspendOnFailure>
                                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                    <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                </suspendOnFailure>
                                <markForSuspension>
                                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                </markForSuspension>
                            </http>
                        </endpoint>
                    </call>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </iterate>
        <property name="result" scope="default">
            <result xmlns=""/>
        </property>
        <!--  Aggregate for collecting DSS response in order to identify target updated row count -->
        <aggregate id="BigQID">
            <completeCondition>
                <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" enclosingElementProperty="result" expression="$body/*[1]">
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="ON Aggregate SEQ" value="called***"/>
                    <property expression="fn:count(//*[local-name()='UpdatedRowCount'])" name="*********BigQueryETL-wso2_dss-TargetCount:: "/>
                </log>
            </onComplete>
        </aggregate>
```

DSS-Code:

```
 <data name="WSO2_TEST_DSS" transports="http https local">
  
   <config id="TestDataSource">
        <property name="carbon_datasource_name">WSO2_ETL_TEST_DB</property>
    </config>
 
   <query id="emp_insert_Q" returnUpdatedRowCount="true" useConfig="TestDataSource">
      <sql>insert into  empdata.employee (name,email,phone) values(?,?,?)</sql>
      <result element="UpdatedRowCount" rowName="" useColumnNumbers="true">
         <element column="1" name="Value" xsdType="integer"/>
      </result>
      <param name="name" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="email" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="phone" sqlType="STRING"/>
      
   </query>
   <operation name="wso2_dss_insert_op">
      <call-query href="emp_insert_Q">
         <with-param name="name" query-param="name"/>
         <with-param name="email" query-param="email"/>
         <with-param name="phone" query-param="phone"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   
</data>
```

What I have understood is that when data volume exceeds more than 8000, Getting ERROR like `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` or `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

ERROR Logs:

```
    [2023-07-18 13:43:17,828] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-252] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded 
at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.readEndElementTag(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:382)at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:211)at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:445)at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:455at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:336)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:199)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.getNext(OMNavigator.java:112)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1113)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.<init>(SwitchingWrapper.java:235)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:74)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:52)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getXMLStreamReader(OMContainerHelper.java:51)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java:736)at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.cloneOMElement(OMElementImpl.java:1038)at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneSOAPEnvelope(MessageHelper.java:690)at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:123)at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)

at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)

at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
```

- To overcome issue, Clearing `heap-dump.hprof` in the `<EI_HOME>/repository/logs` file whenever encountered above ERROR and restarting the container
- But intermittently facing similar issue again.
- There is JVM configuration in Rancher where container management is done. JVM_Initial size is `8192` and JVM_Max size is `32768`

Java version: `1.8.0_171`

Is there any memory leak which we can control via code? or any way to resolve this issue in WSO2 EI?

Comment: You will have to analyze the heap dump and see what's eating up the memory. Just looking at the integration code we can't tell what's happening. What's the size of the heap dump when the issue happens?

Comment: Hi @ycr
Thanks for your reply. heapdump file consumes 1.2 GB

Comment: That seems too small if you have allocated 32GB of memory. I don't think you are really facing an OOM issue. I suspect you have not allocated memory to the JVM properly. Also if you have an external monitoring tools check the memory growth of the pod.

Comment: Hi @ycr As mentioned in question, intermittently facing OOM or heap space issue in this ETL process, can you have any idea on allocation memory to JVM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the JVM memory params, one option is to add the following environment variable to the Pod, `JVM_MEM_OPTS` by setting the Xms and Xmx values.

```
JVM_MEM_OPTS="-Xms8192m -Xmx32768m"
```

Then on the server startup logs, you should see the following logs with the updated memory params.

```
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/xxx/xx/xxx/wso2ei-6.5.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Hi @ycr
I have made changes in integrator.sh file to allocate memory to JVM like JVM_MEM_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m" and process is working fine now, PS: JVM configuration in Rancher which is defined already  not passed to wso2 startup script, so default configuration exists(JVM_MEM_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m") earlier, now this JVM params limit are increased